# read image into protorpc message thru endpoints api

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

To receive a picture from a user into my `@endpoints.method` do I use `messages.BytesField` as in

```
image = messages.BytesField(1)
stuff = messages.StringField(2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is the right strategy. When using Cloud Endpoints, the bytes sent to a `BytesField` must be base64 encoded.

After being sent and validated through Google's API infrastructure, the base64 encoded bytes will be sent along to your `protorpc.remote.Service` class and converted from a base64 string to a native byte-string (instance of `str`) in Python.

So you'll need your clients to take the image bytes and convert them to base64.

To encode a byte string as base64 in Javascript, see [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript), to do the same in Python, simply call

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(byte_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the base64 encoding bit. Say, to send a blob from app-engine to the front-end (here android), must I also encode the blob somehow or do I just send it?

Comment: @KatedralPillon feel free to ask more questions. You can just set the blob as the value of the `BytesField` and when it is served by Endpoints it will be base64 encoded.