# how to display images in android application from Google App Engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

As I new to android development, I have to develop application in which, Google app engine is involved. What I want to do is I want to fetch the images from Google app engine cloud and show it in android application. I am not able to fetch it that image from cloud to android.

Please help...

Thanks,

Comment: are you storing image as blobproperty of datastore or using google cloud storage?

Comment: using blob property of datastore

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/) for sending data from your datastore, including images stored in blobproperty,  to your android client and then display them. You can read upon the details of google cloud endpoints , which also has the sample code and other SO threads for understanding how to setup communication between android and appengine datastore through rest api based on endpoints. I am adding below the details only for blobproperty as it is not mentioned in detail in the document :

1, For sending blobproperty through endpoints, you need to use [BytesField in protorpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576203/read-image-into-protorpc-message-thru-endpoints-api) which will automatically send the pic as **base64 encoded**

2, In android , you define a string property to receive the bytesfield data in the message through endpoints

```
@com.google.api.client.util.Key
    private String pic;
```

3, If you are using sqlite in android to locally store the received image, you should use blob type for the pic column `C_PIC +" blob` and you can insert the received string value into this

4,While reading from android's sqlite database for displaying, you can store the pic into a byte[] and then decode the base64 encoded pic as another byte[] and then convert it into a bitmap and display it using a suitable imageview :

```
byte[] picblob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Yourdatabase.C_PIC));

if (picblob!=null){
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(picblob, Base64.DEFAULT);
               Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check and implement Dynamic Image Server with Google App Engine.

Here you can find example of Java program that can be ported easily for your Android development https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/serving_dynamic_images

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant about Mahesh's answer because, though it provides some client code, that code is not enough and really doesn't compare with the features of newer libraries.

I think the harder part will be the client, so I think it is important that you pick a good client library.  So, you should take a look at Volley and Picasso, and see what best suites your needs.

I think you will find the server side to be easy in comparison, and you should take a look at Google Cloud Storage too.

Also, since you mention you are new to this, I will suggest you avoid a common mistake of automatically picking the Google library/service (volley, in this case).  Google libraries are often not as good as people expect (and have much poorer docs then expected).  I haven't used Picasso, but it is from Square and they are highly regarded for their contributions to Android.