# How to retrieve the image store on app engine using endpoints and how to show/display in Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, endpoints

I have uploaded image on app engine. I am retrieving image blob key in android app from app engine using endpoints. I am doing some code on android app to display image.
The code is

```
URL imageURL = null;
try 
{
    //use our image serve page to get the image URL

    imageURL = new URL("http://yourapp.appspot.com/serveBlob?id=" + o.getImageKey());

} catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
     //Decode and resize the image then set as the icon  
     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

     options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

     options.inSampleSize = 1 / 2;

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactor.decodeStream((InputStream) imageURL.getContent());

     Bitmap finImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false);

     icon.setImageBitmap(finImg);

} catch (IOException e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it gives me `bitmap = null` and throwing null pointer exception.

I am struck on this point from lat 4 days. Please help me.

Comment: Would be nice to put some effort on formatting a code in a better more readable way..

Comment: Yes Lipis I have updated my question with some formating. Is that ok?

Comment: Can you verify that downloading the image from your imageURL with the browser actually works?

Comment: If you are able to successfully retreive your image into your android app, you can check the below answer to see how to [display image in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216239/how-to-display-images-in-android-application-from-google-app-engine/20301555#20301555)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                Log.v("bitmap--", "" + bitmap);
                         icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I understand that the 1rep person can screw up with the format.. but why continuing the trend in the answer as well?!

Comment: Tamilan, it is still getting bitmap-- null it is working same as before code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

First have to create Servlet on app engine side of my project.

Servlet is like this.

```
public class Serve extends HttpServlet  
{
   private BlobstoreService blobstoreService =BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
   {
         BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("id"));
         blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
   }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
   {
      doGet(req, resp);
   }

}
```

Then have to register servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xyz.Serve</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServeBlob</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then create url using servlet in android code.

the code at android side is like this.

```
 URL imageURL = new URL("http://xyz.appspot.com/ServeBlob?id="+blobKey);


    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();

    connection.setDoInput(true);

    connection.connect();

    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

`xyz` is your app engine project name on appspot.
`blobKey` should be the blob key of image store on AppEngine.

Now pass bitmap to image view like this.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id....);

img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```