# How to upload an image through appengine endpoints api?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am using Endpoints Proto Datastore API.
Suppose I have code like this :

Model :

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  _message_fields_schema = ('name', 'image')
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  image = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

API :

```
@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='my api')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

@MyModel.method(name='mymodel.insert', path='mymodel')
def insert_mymodel(self, data):
    data.put()
    return data
```

How can I upload image to the datastore through api?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done it myself but [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576382/3877822). You need to use the bytes type and encode the image into base64:

> When using Cloud Endpoints, the bytes
>   sent to a BytesField must be base64 encoded.
>
> After being sent and validated through Google's API infrastructure,
>   the base64 encoded bytes will be sent along to your
>   protorpc.remote.Service class and converted from a base64 string to a
>   native byte-string (instance of str) in Python.
>
> So you'll need your clients to take the image bytes and convert them
>   to base64.
>
> To encode a byte string as base64 in Javascript, see How can you
>   encode to Base64 using Javascript?, to do the same in Python, simply
>   call
>
> import base64 
>   base64.b64encode(byte_string)

Comment: Thank you very much. It will be very much helpful if you can point me to some example.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you very much.